# Как обратиться к полю в json

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Только начал изучать js.
Есть следующая проблема. Я читаю данные из json файл и у меня все хорошо. Проверяю алертом - значение вытягивается:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("/skiresort/forslider", function( data ) { 
        var items = [];

        $.each(data, function( key, val ) {
            alert(data.max_total_km_of_tails);
        });
    });
});
```

Дальше мне нужно использовать это значение в слайдере, но в ответ я получаю ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined с ошибкой в строке вызова:

```
$(function () {
    var slider = $("#skilable").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: data.max_total_km_of_tails,
        step: 1
    });
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: data не передал в функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что должно быть как-то так:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("/skiresort/forslider", function( data ) { 
        var slider = $("#skilable").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: data.max_total_km_of_tails,
            step: 1
        });
    });
});
```